# force scanf("") to only receive a number 0-7

Tags: c, scanf

I have a task to write a code that would receive a number from 0 to 7 (including edges) and convert it to 4bit binary code in two's complement.

everything is fine with my code. it works and calculation is fine.
but I want to make things nicer by limiting the user from inputting a number that is not 0-7.
right now users can put any number they want but it doesn't make sense in the conversion system...

how can I do that?

thanks...

Comment: Have a loop where it checks the result and asks for another one until the user inputs something between 0 and 7.

Comment: You ask someone to say a number between 1 and 7. He says "8". What do you do?

Comment: What do you mean by "limiting the user from inputting a number that is not 0-7"? Slap their wrist as soon as their finger is near any other key?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Natively you cant, you have to double check input manually- by regex ideally, basically by condition, and if need, then put input into loop to prompt once more time once condition not met, as suggested in this thread

Comment: The nearest you could get is `scanf("%1o")` - it can't prevent the user entering more than one octal digit, but it won't convert more than one.

Comment: Unless your program reads directly from the keyboard (and ignores key codes that don't generate the digits 0 through 7), all you can do is filter what appears via standard input.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it something like that

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int digit;

    while ( scanf( "%u", &digit ) != 1 || 7 < digit )
    {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
    }

    printf( "digit = %u\n", digit );

    return 0;
}
```

If the input is

```
A
8
5
```

then the output is

```
digit = 5
```